# Using a variable to complete a Django query returns 'object has no attribute'

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to create some queries into a product database for shirts. A single table contains all stock and price information (e.g., xs_stock, xs_original_price, xs_sale_price). When a customer adds a product to their cart, it saves what size that is and I'd like to use a variable to make the appropriate queries. For example:

```
size = 'Small'
size_query = 's_original_price'
product.shirtstyle_set.all()[0].size_query 
#substitute in 's_original_price' with query, which would work if typed by hand
```

Instead, I get `AttributeError: 'ShirtStyle' object has no attribute 'size_query'`.

I now know that this isn't the optimal way to set up an inventory database, but I'd like to figure this out before I fix it up. Thanks in advance.

Edit to add my models.py:

```
class ShirtStyle(models.Model):
    shirt = models.ForeignKey(Shirt)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, blank=True)
    pattern = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    xs_stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    xs_original_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=1999, blank=False, null=False)
    xs_sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    s_stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    s_original_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=1999, blank=False, null=False)
    s_sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    m_stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    m_original_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=1999, blank=False, null=False)
    m_sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    l_stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    l_original_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=1999, blank=False, null=False)
    l_sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    xl_stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    xl_original_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=1999, blank=False, null=False)
    xl_sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, there might be deeper issues here on how you structured your data, but try the following:

Try `product.shirtstyle_set.all()[0][size_query]`

Comment: When I try this, it gives me 'ShirtStyle' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. I'm about to update the question to give you my ShirtStyle model.

Answer (score 0):

Got this answered on reddit /r/learnprogramming. Entire answer:

> But to answer your question, "s_original_price' is an attibute of the
>   model instance, not a value in a dict(ionary). So you need to use
>   getattr to get the value of the model field:
>
> ```
> getattr(product.shirtstyle_set.all()[0], size_query)
> ```
>
> instead of:
>
> ```
> product.shirtstyle_set.all()[0][size_query]
> ```